# Faulting application name: tomcat9.exe

Tags: tomcat9, adoptopenjdk

I am trying to install tomcat 9 using `apdoptopenjdk jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot` on windows server 2008 R2. The tomcat starts properly from the command prompt when I ran startup.bat.

I have mentioned correct JVM path in the tomcat configutation dialog box and the mode is also set to JVM. Have cross checked this configuration multiple times and found no issue with it.

But it won't start when I ran from services.msc as a service. 
The issue I get when ran as a service is `1067 terminated unexpectedly`. And when I check the system logs in event viewer it shows below error.

[image: TOMCAT ERROR IN SYSTEM EVENT LOGS]

Please help me as I am trying this since last two weeks.

Comment: Could you please share stderr log details ? Before that please verify folder permissions and owner permission Service account with which you will be running Tomcat service

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a tomcat bug.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63767

I'm following up something similar, but your issue appears to have been fixed in 9.0.27